# Kick all users in a role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im coding my discord bot, and now i want it to kick all users with the role "Unverified", i know how to list users in a role and i know how to kick sbd, but i have no clue how to do that, i tried with putting the listing-code in/after/before the kick thing, but all i get are errors.

The bot is only for one server so there is no need to be able to set the role

This is how i list the users:

```
(message.guild.roles.get('607623318995992579').members.map(m=>m.user.tag).join('\n'))
```

I hope it's working like "+KickUnV"
Answer: "Kicked all users with the Unverified role!"

Comment: What errors are you getting? I have no idea what you mean by `but i have no clue how to do that, i tried with putting the listing-code in/after/before the kick thing, but all i get are errors.`

Comment: As your desired answer was quite simple, I was more than happy to oblige, however, in the future, this is not a complete code-writing forum, you should be coming here with specific questions and most desirably some sort of error. Without such information, this question will not be useful to other members of the community, and most of the time, would lead to no answer being provided.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can help you out here.

A simple way of doing this would be:

```
let members = (message.guild.roles.get('607623318995992579').members)
members.forEach(m => {
    // Your kick methodology, i.e. m.kick(), m being the member from the array.
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Works fine, but i get an error, a reeeealy long one, cant copy it all, but the first line is ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions```
Actually is has the Perms. to kick and stuff

Comment: @RedGaming Yes so I recommend inside your kick methodology you include conditionals that will prevent the bot from trying to kick unkickable members. Basically what I think might be happening is there is a member with that role who you are trying to kick that possibly has another role that prevents the bot from kicking them.

Comment: This should help you `.kickable` [Link](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kickable)